# Segfaults with singletons

Tags: c++, crash, singleton

// Non singleton
    class MyLogManager
    {
      void write(message) {Ogre::LogManager::getSingletonPtr()->logMessage(message);}
    }

```
class Utils : public singleton<Utils>
{
   MyLogManager *handle;
   MyLogManager& getHandle { return *handle; }
};

namespace someNamespace
{
   MyLogManager &Log() { return Utils::get_mutable_instance().getHandle(); }
}

int main()
{
   someNamespace::Log().write("Starting game initializating...");
}
```

In this code I'm using boost's singleton (from serialization) and calling Ogre's log manager (it's singleton-type too).

The program fails at any trying to do something with **Ogre::LogManager::getSingletonPtr()** object with code

`User program stopped by signal (SIGSEGV)`

I checked that **getSingletonPtr()** returns address **0x000**

But using code `Utils::get_mutable_instance().getHandle().write("foo")` works good in another part of program. What's wrong could be there with calling singletons?

---

Real version of Utils class:

```
class Utils : public singleton<Utils>
{
    protected:
        ConfigManager *configHandlePtr;
        LogManager *logHandlePtr;

    public:
        Utils()
        {
            configHandlePtr = new ConfigManager();

            string engineLog = configHandle().getValue<string>("engine.logFilename", "Engine.log");
            logHandlePtr = new LogManager(engineLog);
        }
        ~Utils()
        {
            delete configHandlePtr;
            delete logHandlePtr;
        }

        ConfigManager &configHandle() const { return *configHandlePtr; }
        LogManager &logHandle() const { return *logHandlePtr; }
};
```

And here is the real code of **LogManager** class:

```
class LogManager
{
    protected:
        string mDefaultPath;

    public:
        LogManager(const string &logPath = "Engine.log") :
                mDefaultPath(logPath) { }

        void write(const string &message, const string logFile = "")
        {
            string workPath = mDefaultPath;


            Ogre::LogManager *logHandle = Ogre::LogManager::getSingletonPtr(); // [logHandle=0x000]
            Ogre::Log *log2Handle = logHandle->getLog(workPath); // [SEGFAULT]
            log2Handle->logMessage(message);

            Ogre::LogManager::getSingletonPtr()->logMessage(message);
        }
};
```

**UPDATE:**

I have a static library (there is my engine code) and the main own programm which links static this library. When I call my config handle (which doesn't use Ogre) everything is okay! There is also **resourceManager**, it uses Ogre too. And it fails like **logManager**. Both this managers uses Ogre's singleton. Maybe it's impossible to call it from another library?

Comment: The initialization is crucial here.

Comment: @konrad-rudolph the code is updated

Comment: Is your application multithreaded?

Comment: @alerty, I'm using Ogre and boost and it makes my app multithreaded, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you have typical "[static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12)" - your Utils instance created before one (or both) of other singletons.

Try change Utils::configHandle() to something like this:

```
ConfigManager &configHandle() const {
    static std::auto_ptr<ConfigManager> configHandlePtr(0);
    if (!configHandlePtr.get()) {
       configHandlePtr.reset(new ConfigManager());
       // init configHandlePtr like you want
    }
    return *configHandlePtr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Boost's singleton, but I notice some strange things in your 'Utils' class.

First of all, getHandle returns a reference to handle, but handle is a local variable that goes out of scope if you leave the method, so the reference to it will also be invalid.

Second, you didn't initialize handle in the getHandle method.

Comment: There was typing error, sory. I return `*handle`. And I specially didn't write **getHandle** initialization to make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Ogre LogManager is correctly initialized?

Or maybe with your libraries you have one instance of the singleton in each library and only the one in your main program is correctly initialized?

In this case you have to declare the singletons in your libraries as "extern" but I'm not sure it applies to statically linked libraries.

Comment: Yeah, it works great in another part of code. Look, please, at update.